# How can I center google map based on user location (but not on html5 geolocalization)? (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs, html, google-maps, geolocation

I'm following [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/making-mean-apps-with-google-maps-part-i) tutorial and in the last step of this part the author shows a piece of code:

```
// Get User's actual coordinates based on HTML5 at window load
geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){

    // Set the latitude and longitude equal to the HTML5 coordinates
    coords = {lat:data.coords.latitude, long:data.coords.longitude};

    // Display coordinates in location textboxes rounded to three decimal points
    $scope.formData.longitude = parseFloat(coords.long).toFixed(3);
    $scope.formData.latitude = parseFloat(coords.lat).toFixed(3);

    // Display message confirming that the coordinates verified.
    $scope.formData.htmlverified = "Yep (Thanks for giving us real data!)";

    gservice.refresh($scope.formData.latitude, $scope.formData.longitude);

});
```

When I run his app (which you can check out [here](https://mean-google-maps.herokuapp.com/#/join)) browser asks me if I agree to share my location and - if I do - the map centers and focuses on my real position. But when I deny, the map shows me the center of America (I'm from Europe).

So my question is: Is there a way of centering the map near the users location in case he denies using the real GPS data? For example based on his IP address or host? In that case I don't need an exact location, but e.g. city or country would be nice to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user denies location in the browser, you don't get anything. There is no "general location" fallback. IP may be the only option for any kind of resolution at that point. I did not see anything in user agent that would provide location. When creating a Google map, you can specify default center for the map at instantiation, which in the tutorial he must have done for America.

**EDIT**

Using IP, you should be able to find a service that would resolve the IP to a physical region like this:

[IP to Location](http://ip-api.com/)

Then you can send that location to the Google Maps geocoder to get a point you can center the map to like this:

[Google Maps Geocoding example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-region-us)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes, he centered the map on America manually. I'm aware that IP might be my only option, so could you give me a hint of how to use this data exactly to center the map accordingly?